# Emacs 27.2 not rendering Devanagari fonts properly

Tags: fonts, unicode

I am having problems with Devanagari fonts in Emacs 27.2. I am using the Noto Sans Devanagari font to render the devanagari unicode font block.

When I first start emacs up, everything works fine and the font displays perfectly. However, after I edit in emacs for a while, it no longer renders the font correctly. The following image shows how the font is distorted:

[image]

It seems to be inserting extra spaces between the aksaras which obviously should not be there.

This only happens at certain levels of zoom. When I zoom in close to the text the font is displayed properly, as it is when I zoom out quite far. It is only at middling levels of zoom that the font is distorted.

If anyone has any suggestions for why this might be happening, I'd be very grateful. I have tried different fonts, including Lohit Devanagari, but the same problem appears with each.